# UIImage is not updated after image view is altered

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I am having a very simple, yet, very weird issue when I want to edit my UIImageView (add a border, background color, etc.) and get the final image from it. It gives me the raw image which I initialized with, without altering.

I basically use [SOXPanRotateZoomImageView.swift](https://github.com/spagosx/Swift-Pan-Rotate-Zoom-ImageView/blob/master/Swift-Pan-Rotate-Zoom-ImageView/SOXPanRotateZoomImageView.swift) from [this](https://github.com/spagosx/Swift-Pan-Rotate-Zoom-ImageView) library that applies gestures to my image to rotate, zoom etc.

Below is my code:

```
class ImageEditorViewController: UIViewController {

  public init(rawImage: UIImage?) {
    self.image = rawImage
    
    super.init(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let editedImageView = SOXPanRotateZoomImageView(image: self.image)
    self.panView.addSubview(editedImageView)
    editedImageView.backgroundColor = .red
    editedImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    let pickedImage = editedImageView.image // Here is original image, without altering..
  }
}
```

In **editedImageView** I can see changes but when I want to access its image, it is the original image. Some asked questions previously recommend `setNeedsDisplay()` and I applied `editedImageView.setNeedsDisplay()`; it does not help. Please do let me know if I need to provide more info or make it more clear. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [SOXPanRotateZoomImageView.swift](https://github.com/spagosx/Swift-Pan-Rotate-Zoom-ImageView/blob/master/Swift-Pan-Rotate-Zoom-ImageView/SOXPanRotateZoomImageView.swift) performs rotation, pan and pinch to `UIImageView` not the `UIImage`.
In other words, it changes ui container, not the image instance.

So when you try to get image like `let pickedImage = editedImageView.image` you're receiving original one.

If you want to perform & save changes to image, you have to look for other library or write it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @Mikhail Vasilev for the reply, as you may see in `SOXPanRotateZoomImageView.swift`, it just extends to UIImageView and adds gestures on image view. It neither changes image view nor image in terms of the border, background color, etc. That means if I use a normal UIImageView, the result won't change. I may need to find a way to capture UIImageView and proceed instead of UIImage.